# carousel-caption move right and take half of carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make my bootstrap 3 `carousel-caption` take half of my `carousel`, to make `caption` background-color a little transparent, and write some text into it.

So the logic is that in `carousel` background I will have pictures and for every picture `caption` will take half of `carousel` whit custom text.

See my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/jy989rkt/3/) example, and I want to make it like this.[image]

So far I manage to set up background of `carousel-caption`, and I know how to pull it to the left, the problem is right side, it's just confusing how does `float: right` want work, further more there is a small `padding-bottom` so how can I remove this? Can any one help me over come this and build it properly, thanks.

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>

                    <p>This is an example layout with carousel that uses the Bootstrap 3 styles.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/2" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>

                    <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 3 -->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/3" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>

                    <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Carousel CSS:

```
#carouselButtons {
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #428bca;
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close - I added a reference to jquery in your fiddle, but the alignment issues you were facing were resolved by using the bottom and right properties.  Float was not the way to go here, since you already had .carousel-caption positioned absolutely, I just added a right:0, and a bottom:0 to your class.

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #428bca;
    opacity: 0.8;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

See the updated Fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/jy989rkt/4/

Comment: Thank you for explaining me this, just to make clear, I will use `float` when I put my element in `relative` state or not?

Comment: Even if you used position:relative, you could still use top, right, bottom, left, but you would then be positioning that element relative to itself, where as position:absolute means that you are positioning that element relative to the next parent element which has relative (or absolute) positioning.  It's a bit confusing at first.  This may help https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/